# jQuery on/off click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to intercept a click on the page and execute some validation logic and let the flow go on.

I have a link:

```
<a data-link="true">Link</a>
```

Js to intercept:

```
$("a[data-link='true'").off("click.link").on("click.link", (event) => this.validate(event));
```

In validate function I just make some validations and I need to proceed with the request.

How can I intercept the click and If validation it's ok, proceed with the original request ?

Thanks.

Comment: there are two functions that uses data selector and event.preventDefault() isn't stoping the request made by the link (by other function)

Answer (score 0):

Your `data` selector might do better if it was more generalized:

```
$(function(){
    // Listen for data link in general
    $('a[data-link]').on('click',function(e){
        // Stop all request
        e.preventDefault();
        // Get the link href
        var hrefPath    =   $(this).attr('href');
        // If the data-link is set to true
        if($(this).data('link') === true) {
            // Do your validation here, not sure if your validation function
            // works or not, but here is where you apply it
            var valid   =   true;
            // If failed, set the default path to empty
            if(!valid)
                hrefPath = false;
            // If the path is not empty, go to the default path
            if(hrefPath !== false)
                window.location =   hrefPath;
            // Stop
            return false;
        }
        // If the link is not true, just go to the default path
        window.location =   hrefPath;
    });
});
```

Comment: the problem is that there is another $('a[data-link]').on('click'... on the app and this code is making the request. the e.preventDefault(); in my function isn't stopping the request

Comment: If you are not getting the prevent to work, you are probably getting a JavaScript error or your other piece of js is overriding this. Put all your js up.

Comment: I should clarify, put in the relevant code you are referring to.